# Convert OpenCV matrix to C Array to be used with CUDA

Tags: arrays, opencv, cuda

I used this function to fill openCV with a certain C array:

```
float data[9] = { 1, 0.5,-51,0,1,50,0,0,1}; 
Mat myH = cv::Mat(3, 3, CV_32F, data);
```

but I wonder if there is another function that does the opposite like this for matrix A:

```
float myArray [Size_Of_A] = Mat A;
```

I know I can do it with a loop, but it's my last option if there is no function to do it. 
The loop would be like:

```
float myArray[size_of_A];
for (int row = 0; row < A.rows; row++)
    for (int col = 0; col < A.cols; col++)
        myArray[row * A.cols + col ] = A.at<float>(row, col);
```

I need that to send an image to CUDA kernel.

Comment: `float* myArray = myH.ptr<float>();`

Comment: so I can simply use the new pointer for the kernel no need to copy anything, right?

Comment: data should be copied to the device, right? You can get the `float*` to the data inside the matrix in this way (no copy), then you need to copy the data to the device (copy)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got this answer from Miki comment,

```
float* myArray = myH.ptr<float>();
```

so no need to duplicate the data on the host side, and we can copy to the device using the new pointer 'myArray'.